# Set GSettings setting only for a specific application

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, gnome-shell

A certain application needed a font change to be easier to read.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface document-font-name "Cantarell 25"
```

The application itself doesn't have a settings dialog for this, but that worked. This changed the font from the default e.g. `Noto Sans 15`. However, the change affected other applications in the system, and now their font size is perhaps too large.

Although the setting was appropriate for one application it wasn't appropriate for the rest.

I am looking for a way to set a GSettings/Dconf setting for a single application without changing the setting "globally".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've reworded it. I thought I was being clear. Could you point which specific parts are confusing?